# Is ZF+Omega rule for sets a complete theory?

Tags: first-order-logic, alternative-set-theories

**Omega rule for sets$``\omega^{ Set}"$:** if $\{\varphi_0(y),\varphi_1(y), \varphi_2(y),...\}$ is the set of all formulas in the language of $ZF$ in one free variable symbol $``y"$, and if $\psi(x)$ is a formula in one free variable symbol $``x"$, then

From: for each $n=0,1,2,3,...; \text{ we have }\forall x \ [x=\{y|\varphi_n(y)\} \to \psi(x) ]$

We Infer:
$\forall x \ [\psi(x)]$

> Question: Is $ZF + \omega^{Set}$ complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  In fact, the set of theorems of $ZF + \omega^{Set}$ is exactly the same as the set of theorems of $ZF+V=HOD$, which is an ordinary recursively axiomatizable first-order theory and is therefore incomplete (assuming ZF is consistent).

First, note that every definable set is ordinal-definable (here and below, "definable" always means without parameters).  Your "$\omega$-rule" then implies that every set is ordinal-definable, so $ZF + \omega^{Set}$ proves $V=HOD$.

Conversely, I claim that every model $M$ of $ZF+V=HOD$ is a model of $ZF + \omega^{Set}$, and so $ZF + \omega^{Set}$ cannot prove any theorems which are not theorems of $ZF+V=HOD$.  To see this, note that first that since $M\vDash V=HOD$ there is a definable (internal) well-ordering of $M$. Now  suppose $\forall x \ [\psi(x)]$ is false in $M$ for some formula $\psi$.  Then there is a definable element $a\in M$ such that $M\vDash\neg\psi(a)$, namely the least such $a$ with respect to the definable well-ordering of $M$.  Say $a$ is defined by the formula $\varphi$.  Then $a=\{y\mid\varphi_n(y)\}$ where $\varphi_n(y)$ is $\forall x(\varphi(x)\rightarrow y\in x)$.  Thus $M\vDash\neg\forall x \ [x=\{y|\varphi_n(y)\} \to \psi(x) ]$.  Since $\psi$ was arbitrary, your $\omega$-rule is sound in $M$ and $M$ is a model of $ZF + \omega^{Set}$.

Comment: but ZF interprets PA, and here with $\omega^{Set}$, we have this theory interpreting PA+omega rule, which is complete for arithmetic, I don't think any model of ZF satisfying your qualifications would interpret PA+omega rule. So I think this answer is not correct as far as the details given is concerned?

Comment: How does your theory interpret PA+omega rule, exactly?  Having an omega rule with respect to all definable sets is quite different from having an omega rule with respect to all standard natural numbers.

Comment: I'm not sure really, but it should do. If you have a non-standard natural then you must be able to violate $\omega^{Set}$, it just cannot be the case that PA + omega rule be stronger than this theory?

Comment: Note that if you similarly added an omega rule for PA that used all _definable_ numbers instead of just the standard natural numbers, you would get a theory that is no stronger than PA, since any nonempty definable subset of a model of PA has a definable element (its least element).

Comment: @Zuhair "If you have a non-standard natural then you must be able to violate $\omega^{Set}$" Why? Having a nonstandard natural *doesn't* mean that there is an undefinable element in the model. The issue is simple: $(1)$ Any model of ZF in which every element is parameter-freely definable automatically satisfies $\omega^{Set}$. $(2)$ In any model $M$ of ZF + V=HOD, the substructure $Def(M)$ of parameter-freely definable elements of $M$ is an elementary substructure of $M$, hence is a model of ZF in which every element is definable.

Comment: So any model of ZF + V=HOD has an elementary submodel consisting of only parameter-freely definable elements. This means that this elementary submodel satisfies $\omega^{Set}$, and hence by elementarity so does the whole original model.

Comment: @EricWofsey, I see your point. Thanks

Comment: @NoahSchweber, hmm.. I see your point. Thanks

Comment: @Zuhair Take for example a (necessarily!) non-$\omega$-model $M$ of ZF + V=HOD + $\neg$Con(ZF+V=HOD). Then every element of $Def(M)$ is parameter-freely definable in $Def(M)$, but by elementarity $Def(M)$ is definitely *not* an $\omega$-model since it sees a contradiction in ZF+V=HOD.

Comment: Incidentally, the use of the submodel of definable elements of $M$ turns out to be unnecessary and kind of a distraction from the main point--you can make the argument directly in $M$ using its definable well-ordering.  I've edited the answer to do so.

Comment: Sure, but ... elementary submodels! They're the best!

Comment: @Zuhair I strongly recommend ([again](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2821049/epsilon-omega-rule-and-standard-models-of-zfc/2821116)) the Hamkins/Linetsky/Reitz paper on [pointwise-definable models of ZF](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4597) - I think it's a good source for dispelling certain reasonable-but-incorrect intuitions.