# Paradox vs Tautology.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, higher-order-logic, logic-translation, nonclassical-logic

The expression(~p or p )is a Tautology.
Consider this statement(p): *This statement is false.*
Now here, Statement p is paradoxical.
My question is :- Can we define paradoxes like this as *statements which prove Tautologies wrong?*

Comment: As an interesting aside, in natural language there are also "anti-paradoxes" like "This statement is true." It turns out that - just as paradoxical statements in natural language wind up yielding important ideas in formal logic - "anti-paradoxes" also reveal rich mathematical structure; see [this old math.stackexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2135587/variant-of-g%C3%B6del-sentence) for some discussion on this (and note that at first glance, the answers there appear to contradict each other!).

Answer (score 4):

No. A paradox doesn't just *assert something incorrect* (e.g. "$0\not=0$") - it asserts something which *cannot be consistently assigned a truth value*. Just implying the negation of a tautology doesn't mean that a statement is paradoxical: e.g. "$p$ and $\neg p$" is not a paradox, it's just a false statement.

Answer (score 0):

A statement can be provable or not provable, and it can be sound (something we expect to be true, like 1+1=2) or unsound (we expect it to be false, like 1+1=3).

A paradox arises when a statement is unsound but provable.  It indicates an error in the logic.

The claim of the speaker in the liar's paradox is clearly unsound: it contradicts itself.  But we have no reason to believe it is provable.  So it only has 1 of the 2 qualifications needed to be a paradox.

> Can we define paradoxes like this as statements which prove Tautologies wrong?

No.  A paradox isn't only defined by what it proves (unsound claims) , but by the fact that the statement itself is provable.