# Decidability of Gödel sentences.

Tags: logic, computability, incompleteness, peano-axioms, decidability

Letting $\text{Pr}(x)$ be a formula that weakly represents the set $\{x:x\text{ is a Gödel code of a provable sentence in PA}\}$, where PA means Peano Arithmetic.

Gödel's first incompleteness theorem shows that there is a sentence $\phi$ such that $$\text{PA}\vdash (\phi \leftrightarrow \neg \text{Pr}(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner)).$$ The theorem shows that $\phi$ is true but not provable in PA.

Now consider the following two sentences $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that: $$ \text{PA}\vdash(\alpha \leftrightarrow \text{Pr}(\ulcorner \alpha\urcorner)\vee \text{Pr}(\ulcorner\text{Pr}(\ulcorner \alpha\urcorner) \urcorner)) \quad\text{and}\quad \text{PA}\vdash(\beta \leftrightarrow \text{Pr}(\ulcorner \beta\urcorner)\wedge \text{Pr}(\ulcorner\text{Pr}(\ulcorner \beta\urcorner) \urcorner)).$$ Is $\alpha$ (resp. $\beta$) decidable in PA? Is $\alpha$ (resp. $\beta$) true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, *positive* self-referentiality with the provability relation results in **PA theorems** (so there's a bit of asymmetry here). Specifically, [Lob's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6b%27s_theorem) says that whenever PA proves $Pr(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner)\rightarrow\varphi$ then PA already proves $\varphi$.

This immediately gives that PA proves $\alpha$. As for $\beta$, [PA proves that PA is $\Sigma_1$-complete](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258431/who-first-proved-that-we-can-prove-that-we-prove-things-we-prove), so in particular PA proves $Pr(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner)\rightarrow Pr(\ulcorner Pr(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner)\urcorner)$ for each $\varphi$; so PA proves $Pr(\ulcorner\beta\urcorner)\rightarrow\beta$, and we may again use Lob's theorem to conclude that PA proves $\beta$.

---

Incidentally, Lob's theorem does use a mild assumption on the provability predicate; there are pathological things one might call "provability predicates" to which it doesn't apply. See the discussion at [this earlier MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2135587/variant-of-g%C3%B6del-sentence).