# Is the set of Gödel numbers of variable-free true sentences of the natural number structure, PA-definable?

Tags: number-theory, model-theory

Let our first-order signature be $(N;+,\cdot,<,0,1)$. Let $S$ be the set of true first-order sentences of that sentences that have no variables, not even bound to a quantifier. For example, $((1>1 \vee 1<(1+1)) \land 1=1)$ belongs to $S$. Let $G(S)$ be the set of godel numbers of $S$, for an arbitrary Gödel numbering $G$. Is $G(S)$ definable in Peano Arithmetic (PA)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$G(S)$ is computable, since comparison of terms in the language of arithmetic is computable, and so $G(S)$ is a fortiori arithmetically definable. In particular, it is $\Delta^0_1$.

However, there is an important point re: language to make here. It's not really proper to talk about a theory defining something. Definability takes place in structures/languages; theories *prove* things. Hence my use of the term "arithmetically definable" above. The connection with a specific theory comes in when we ask what is needed to prove basic facts about *(some fixed definition of)* the set in question. Here, for instance, the equivalence between **computability** and **representability over (say) Robinson arithmetic** tells us that $\mathsf{PA}$ is massive overkill for answering individual membership questions about $G(S)$.

(Re: the italicized parenthetical, using a pathological definition of $G(S)$ could change the picture. For example, letting $\gamma$ be some fixed "reasonable" definition of $G(S)$, consider the formula $\theta(x)\equiv$ "$\gamma(x)\leftrightarrow Con(\mathsf{PA})$." This $\theta$ also defines $G(S)$, but $\mathsf{PA}$ can't prove the equivalence between $\theta$ and $\gamma$; from $\mathsf{PA}$'s perspective, it's also possible that $\theta$ is equivalent to $\neg\gamma$ instead! See also [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2135659/28111) for a related issue regarding pathological expressions, this time in the context of Lob's theorem.)